# Eclipse Android Development src folder empty

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, src

I am aware that this question has been asked before but the answers didn't solve my problem so I wanted to ask it again. I am quite new at android development. I am using the 3.7.2 Indigo version of Eclipse right now. I launched the ADT plugin but when I try to create a new Android Application Project src and layout folders are created empty. I already tried some solutions such as clicking on "Install New Software" and paste the adt link but I get an error "duplicate location" then. Can anyone offer me some solution?

Comment: Try downloading the latest ADT Bundle from the website http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Comment: The above information correct

Comment: I tried but now it gives an error: "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.  Please update ADT to the latest version."  There cannot be any update found. And when I tried the link on the ADT update page it can't complete the installation.

Comment: Check the installation folder of android (outside Eclipse) and launch the sdk manager.exe. This will connect to internet and let you update the android framework. Once is done then open eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have checked the **Create Activity** checkbox, otherwise the activity will not be created by default. 
Incase you haven't ,you may still create an activity by right-clicking on the project and **New > Other > Android > Android Activity**. But you have to make sure you check the Launcher Activity checkbox in case it is the first activity of your application.

Comment: Tried that to but it didn't solve my problem unfortunately. I tried to delete eclipse and launched again another version but my problem is still there.

Comment: Launch the SDKManager.exe from your <android-home> and make sure all the important libraires are installed and updated

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue for 2 days now.
Searched through countless posts and countless suggestions.
All very helpful but did not work.

I finally cracked this problem!!!!

With the new ADT kit I was selecting "Blank Activity"

This morning I tried "Empty Activity"

Eureka!!! This creates the Main activity.